# Python function to find specific regex in the text of an XML document

Tags: python, regex, xml

I'm writing a code that, starting from an XML file:

- stores the index of child elements of a tag and the child elements as
  key, values in a dictionary (function `get_xml_by_tag_names`);
- deletes keys whose values contain a certain string (the specific text
  size) and puts these keys and the corresponding values into a second
  dictionary (def `search_delete_append`);
- joins, for each dictionary, the dict values and extracts their
  text(def `main`);
- replaces certain values with "" (def `main`);
- counts the occurrences of specific regex I specify (def `find_regex`).

The `main` function is problematic, as I need help cleaning it up, the regex are too many and I want to create a function for each regex inside the main function. Would it be a good option?

```
import re
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def get_xml_by_tag_names(xml_path, tag_name_1, tag_name_2):

    data = {}
    xml_tree = minidom.parse(xml_path)
    item_group_nodes = xml_tree.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_1)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_2)
        for _ in cl_compile_nodes:
            data[idx]=[item_group_node.toxml()]
    return data


def find_regex(regex, text):
    lista = []
    for x in text:
        matches_prima = re.findall(regex, x)
        lunghezza = len(matches_prima)
        lista.append(lunghezza)
    print("The number of {} matches is ".format(regex), sum(lista))

def find_regex_fasi(regex, text):
    matches_fasi = re.findall(regex, text)
    print("Numero di corpo minore è", len(matches_fasi))


def search_delete_append(dizionario, dizionariofasi):
    deletekeys = []
    insertvalues = []
    for k in dizionario:
        for v in dizionario[k]:
            if "7.489" in v:
                deletekeys.append(k)
                dizionariofasi[k] = v

    for item in deletekeys:
        del dizionario[item]


def main():
    dict_fasi = {}
    data = get_xml_by_tag_names('output2.xml', 'new_line', 'text')
    search_delete_append(data, dict_fasi)

    testo = []
    for value in data.values():
        myxml = ' '.join(value)
        tree = ET.fromstring(myxml)
        tmpstring = ' '.join(text.text for text in tree.findall('text'))
        for to_remove in ("<", ">", ".", ",", ";", "-", "!", ":", "’", "?", "<>", "=", "|", "(", ")"):
            tmpstring = tmpstring.replace(to_remove, "")
        testo.append(tmpstring)
    #testo = ''.join(testo)
    print(testo)
    find_fase_12T_leo = re.compile(r"\]\s*AN\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*T")
    #find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")
    find_fase_base_2 = re.compile(r"\]\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\sT")  # ] parole → T
    find_fase_base_3 = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] parole da cui T
    find_fase_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+[^T])")  # ] 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
    find_fase_prima_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s+prima\s+1\s+([\w\s]+)\s+2([\w\s]+[^T])")  # ] prima 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
    find_fase_prima_123 = re.compile(r"\]\sprima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s3([\w\s]+)")
    find_fase_prima_123T = re.compile(r"\]\sprima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s3\sT") #prima 1 parole 2 parole 3t
    find_fase_prima_1freccia2 = re.compile(r"\]\s+prima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\s2([\w\s]+[^T])") #] prima 1 parola → 2 parola
    FIND_FASE12T = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\sT")
    FIND_FASE123T_OPZ2 = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s][^3|^3T]+) ")
    FIND_FASE123T = re.compile(r"\]\s*1([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s3\sT")
    FIND_FASE_123FRECCIAT = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s→\sT")
    FIND_FASE_1FRECCIA23T = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s→\s2([\w\s]+)\s(T|3\sT)")
    FIND_FASE_FRECCIA1F2FT = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s→\s2([\w\s]+)\s→\s(T|3\sT)")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_123FRECCIAT = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*T")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA23T = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*(T|3\sT)")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_FRECCIA1F2FT = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*(T|3\sT)")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA2 = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_12345T = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s]+)\s*5\sT")
    FIND_FASE_PRIMA_12345T_OPZ2 = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s][^5|^5\sT]+)")
    FIND_FASE_12345T = re.compile(r"\]\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s]+)\s*5\sT")

    #find_da = re.compile(r"\]\s*da(?!\S)")
    #find_da_cui = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui")
    #find_sps = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*sps")
    #find_su = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*su")
    #find_as = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*as")
    #find_ins = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*ins")
    #find_segue = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*segue")
    find_regex(FIND_FASE12T, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_12T_leo, testo)
    #find_regex(find_prima, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_base_2, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_base_3, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_12, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_12, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_123, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_123T, testo)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_1freccia2, testo)
    #find_regex(find_da, testo)
    #find_regex(find_da_cui, testo)
    #find_regex(find_sps, testo)
    #find_regex(find_su, testo)
    #find_regex(find_as, testo)
    #find_regex(find_ins, testo)
    #find_regex(find_segue, testo)
    #################

    testo_fasi = []
    values = [x for x in dict_fasi.values()]
    myxml_fasi = ' '.join(values)
    find_CM = re.compile(r"10\.238")
    find_regex_fasi(find_CM, myxml_fasi) #quanti CM ci sono?
    #print(myxml_fasi)
    for x in dict_fasi.values():
        xxx= ''.join(x)
        tree2 = ET.fromstring(xxx)
        tmpstring2 = ' '.join(text.text for text in tree2.findall('text'))
        for to_remove in ("<", ">", ".", ",", ";", "-", "!", ":", "’", "?", "<>", "=", "|", "(", ")"):
            tmpstring2 = tmpstring2.replace(to_remove, "")
        testo_fasi.append(tmpstring2)
    #testo_fasi = ''.join(testo_fasi)
    print(testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE12T, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE123T_OPZ2, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE123T, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_1FRECCIA23T, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_123FRECCIAT, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_FRECCIA1F2FT, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA23T, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_PRIMA_123FRECCIAT, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_PRIMA_FRECCIA1F2FT, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA2, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_PRIMA_12345T, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_PRIMA_12345T_OPZ2, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(FIND_FASE_12345T, testo_fasi)

    find_regex(find_fase_12T_leo, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_prima, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_fase_base_2, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_fase_base_3, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_fase_12, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_12, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_123, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_123T, testo_fasi)
    find_regex(find_fase_prima_1freccia2, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_da, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_da_cui, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_sps, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_su, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_as, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_ins, testo_fasi)
    #find_regex(find_segue, testo_fasi)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I know it's half in Italian right now, but I need to keep it for now for my clarity.

Comment: Hey. Could you reduce this to a minimal working example? Perhaps include a valid minimal input and the corresponding output too?

Comment: Should I provide it even if everything is working?

Answer (score 3):

**We should only use as many variables as needed**

For example,

```
values = [x for x in dict_fasi.values()]
myxml_fasi = ' '.join(values)
```

could be

```
myxml_fasi = ' '.join(dict_fasi.values())
```

---

**We can reduce the number of strings created**

```
for to_remove in ("<", ">", ".", ",", ";", "-", "!", ":", "’", "?", "<>", "=", "|", "(", ")"):
    tmpstring2 = tmpstring2.replace(to_remove, "")
```

could be

```
tmpstring2 = ''.join(c for c in tmpstring2
                     if c not in set("|=?-<>’(!.:,;"))
```

The first creates a new string with each iteration. 
N.b. after deleting `<` and `>`, there won't be any `<>` in the text.

---

**Separating input/output from processing functions**

I'd try to limit interaction with the world to as few functions as possible. For example I would not expect a function named `find_regex_fasi` to print anything to the console (or elsewhere). I'd make it return its results and do the printing inside `main`.

---

```
find_fase_12T_leo = re.compile(r"\]\s*AN\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*T")
#find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")
find_fase_base_2 = re.compile(r"\]\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\sT")  # ] parole → T
find_fase_base_3 = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] parole da cui T
find_fase_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+[^T])")  # ] 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
find_fase_prima_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s+prima\s+1\s+([\w\s]+)\s+2([\w\s]+[^T])")  # ] prima 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
find_fase_prima_123 = re.compile(r"\]\sprima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s3([\w\s]+)")
find_fase_prima_123T = re.compile(r"\]\sprima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s3\sT") #prima 1 parole 2 parole 3t
find_fase_prima_1freccia2 = re.compile(r"\]\s+prima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\s2([\w\s]+[^T])") #] prima 1 parola → 2 parola
FIND_FASE12T = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\sT")
FIND_FASE123T_OPZ2 = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s][^3|^3T]+) ")
FIND_FASE123T = re.compile(r"\]\s*1([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s3\sT")
FIND_FASE_123FRECCIAT = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s→\sT")
FIND_FASE_1FRECCIA23T = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s→\s2([\w\s]+)\s(T|3\sT)")
FIND_FASE_FRECCIA1F2FT = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s→\s2([\w\s]+)\s→\s(T|3\sT)")
FIND_FASE_PRIMA_123FRECCIAT = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*T")
FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA23T = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*(T|3\sT)")
FIND_FASE_PRIMA_FRECCIA1F2FT = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*(T|3\sT)")
FIND_FASE_PRIMA_1FRECCIA2 = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)")
FIND_FASE_PRIMA_12345T = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s]+)\s*5\sT")
FIND_FASE_PRIMA_12345T_OPZ2 = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s][^5|^5\sT]+)")
FIND_FASE_12345T = re.compile(r"\]\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s]+)\s*5\sT")

#find_da = re.compile(r"\]\s*da(?!\S)")
#find_da_cui = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui")
#find_sps = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*sps")
#find_su = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*su")
#find_as = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*as")
#find_ins = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*ins")
#find_segue = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*segue")
find_regex(FIND_FASE12T, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_12T_leo, testo)
#find_regex(find_prima, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_base_2, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_base_3, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_12, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_prima_12, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_prima_123, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_prima_123T, testo)
find_regex(find_fase_prima_1freccia2, testo)
#find_regex(find_da, testo)
#find_regex(find_da_cui, testo)
#find_regex(find_sps, testo)
#find_regex(find_su, testo)
#find_regex(find_as, testo)
#find_regex(find_ins, testo)
#find_regex(find_segue, testo)
```

can become something like

```
find_phase_regexes = {
    k: re.compile(v) for k, v in {
        "12T_leo":  r"\]\s*AN\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*T",
        "prima": r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)",
        "base_2":      r"\]\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\sT",  # ] parole → T
        "base_3": r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT",  # ] parole da cui T
        "12": r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+[^T])",  # ] 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
        "prima_12": r"\]\s+prima\s+1\s+([\w\s]+)\s+2([\w\s]+[^T])",  # ] prima 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
        "prima_123": r"\]\sprima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s3([\w\s]+)",
        "prima_123T": r"\]\sprima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s3\sT", #prima 1 parole 2 parole 3t
        "prima_1freccia2": r"\]\s+prima\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\s2([\w\s]+[^T])", #] prima 1 parola → 2 parola
        "12T": r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\sT",
        "123T_OPZ2": r"\]\s*prima\s*1([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s][^3|^3T]+) ",
        "123T": r"\]\s*1([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s3\sT",
        "123FRECCIAT": r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2([\w\s]+)\s→\sT",
        "1FRECCIA23T": r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s→\s2([\w\s]+)\s(T|3\sT)",
        "FRECCIA1F2FT": r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s→\s2([\w\s]+)\s→\s(T|3\sT)",
        "PRIMA_123FRECCIAT": r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*T",
        "PRIMA_1FRECCIA23T": r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*(T|3\sT)",
        "PRIMA_FRECCIA1F2FT": r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*(T|3\sT)",
        "PRIMA_1FRECCIA2": r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*→\s*2([\w\s]+)",
        "PRIMA_12345T": r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s]+)\s*5\sT",
        "PRIMA_12345T_OPZ2": r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s][^5|^5\sT]+)",
        "12345T": r"\]\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)\s*2([\w\s]+)\s*3([\w\s]+)\s*4([\w\s]+)\s*5\sT",
    }.items()
}

for k, v in find_phase_regexes.items():
    find_regex(v, testo)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### str.maketrans and str.translate

`str.maketrans()` is much faster than:

```
 for to_remove in ("<", ">", ".", ",", ";", "-", "!", ":", "’", "?", "<>", "=", "|", "(", ")"):
        tmpstring = tmpstring.replace(to_remove, "")
```

Instead:

```
# create the table once at the beginning of main or globally
table = str.maketrans({c:None for c in "<>.,;-!:’?=|()"})

# then do this instead of the for-loop
tmpstring = tmpstring.translate(table)
```